# Why is my XAML Designer spacing out in MS Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, app.xaml

When trying to design my first XAML window, MainWindow.xaml I noticed it was jumping around with what I think are resolution problems. It looks like this:

[resolution problem in xaml designer?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhijD.png)

But when I run the debugger it looks as I had supposed it to,
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZhTs.png)

the code is nothing more than [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYGkq.png) basicly the grid and the controls.

specs:

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10870H CPU @ 2.20GHz

16 GB RAM

NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU

Windows 11 Pro

For some reason I just can't seem to figure out what is causing these problems, does anyone have a solution?

EDIT: I have tried reinstalling GPU drivers but this didn't work, all drivers are up to date. Reinstalling VS 2022 did nothing.

Comment: I haven't seen misbehavior like that in 2022, can't recall anything specifically like that in 2019, but I have seen some issues in 2019 which tend to resolve by restarting Visual Studio and rebuilding the relevant assemblies. I'd assume 2022 has carried over a lot of quirks from 2019, so I'd start with cleaning the solution and restarting Visual Studio. FWIW I sometimes get quirky output due to the designer failing to keep up with my edits.

Comment: @Zenilogix thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately this didn't help me, I have  reinstalled Visual Studio 2022, during this process I noticed that hyperlinks and buttons inside the VS intaller are also acting in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by Nahimic software interfering with the rendering in WPF / XAML.

I found [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nahimic-software-break-wpf-rendering-on-rtx-setups/187309) forum about it, unfortunately there is no permanent fix as Nahimic gets installed / activated with each Windows cumulative update.

So basicly just disable it though the task manager when it happens and hope Windows fixes it in the future.

Having identified my own problem I also found [this](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/707) forum, some people had problems even without Nahimic so it might be of help if my answer wasn't helping.